# Upload files with Q&A admin

Tags: plugins

Is there any way to create functionality in Wordpress which allows

1. Logged in users can upload documents to the admin
2. Admin can see the document and add notes
3. Admin can also upload the document for the user
4. User can also add notes for the admin

Answer (score 0):

Below plugin should help you get the feature much faster
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nmedia-user-file-uploader/

Comment: Thanks. I will try this plugin.